# spacify, changing background and mobile adjustment JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Last week we got a quick test from a company, that involved JS. The task was meant to do as much as you could in JavaScript.

The tasks were: 
1. Implement a "spacify" function on String, that returns a string with spaces between all characters only for use on h1. (never heard of it before, but im guessing that it's like letter spacing? But how does it actually work?)

2. Add content from headerText variable to h1 item (no problem with this one, but if there is another way, i'd like to know (:)
3. Set random backgroundColor on each article
   (I found out how to do it for a single ID. But I want it to be on all articles where each of them have different colors, that switch whenever the site is loaded, how do you do that with the code i wrote?)
4. Make articles display in 5 columns. (I suppose you can just use a simple float? As I have problems seeing how you can use grid on this one.)
5. All content must be visible and each rows items must have equal heights. (this one is easy enough, and i don't need help for it, but how can i loop it out so i only have to write it ONE time, and not multiple times?)
6. Adjust columns on smaller screens => 2 columns on mobile screens, and 3 on tablet. 
   (I've never heard of anything like Mobile adaptions through Javascript, so what exactly do you do, if you are only allowed to use JS?)
7. Create a hover effect that looks like the attached gif-animation.

My code (I know some of it is wrong.. but as I tried my best please be kind)

```js
var headerText = spacify('hello world')

var spacify = funtion(str) {

    return str.split('').join(' ');
};

document.getElementById("overskrift").innerHTML = headerText;

    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var bgColor = "rgba(" + x + "," + y + "," + z + ")";
var a = getElementsByTagName(article);

function random() {
        style.background = bgColor;
        style.width = "20%";
        style.height = "260px";
        style.cssFloat = "left";
    }

random();
```

```css
html, body {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

article {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="overskrift"></h1>


<section>
    <article id="r1" class="Artikler" onmouseover="bg_Image(this)">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur velit dui, consectetur pretium ipsum sed, placerat elementum augue. In quis suscipit enim. Suspendisse potenti.
            Sed vehicula mauris non sodales molestie.Nulla euismod justo at rutrum fringilla.
        </p>
    </article>

    <article onmouseover="bg_Image(this)">
        <p>Praesent convallis sem eu enim viverra, et porta augue porttitor. Ut euismod iaculis metus in suscipit. Curabitur consectetur velit a ligula lobortis dapibus.</p>
    </article>

    <article onmouseover="bg_Image(this)">
        <p>
            Vivamus egestas velit sed libero maximus, tempor dapibus lacus tempus. Proin tristique est eros, eget consectetur diam eleifend et. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
            et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
        </p>
    </article>

    <article onmouseover="bg_Image(this)">
        <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec faucibus metus et dolor sagittis accumsan. Morbi non dolor vestibulum, dictum risus nec, efficitur arcu.</p>
    </article>

    <article onmouseover="bg_Image(this)">
        <p>Aliquam suscipit urna nec faucibus euismod. Proin suscipit facilisis ullamcorper. In ultrices sodales massa, eu auctor eros interdum sed.</p>
    </article>

    @*break*@

    <article onmouseover="bg_Image(this)">
        <p>
            Praesent et ullamcorper mi, eget porttitor tellus. Fusce sem sapien, faucibus at condimentum dictum, commodo vitae risus. Nullam sit amet sodales diam.
            Integer eu dolor ut lacus posuere tincidunt a nec augue.
        </p>
    </article>

    <article onmouseover="bg_Image(this)" onmouseout="bgColor">
        <p>
            Vestibulum mollis felis vitae eros facilisis, sit amet scelerisque massa scelerisque. Vivamus vitae malesuada dui. Donec ut sapien id sem feugiat
            elementum ac ac orci. Fusce dictum eleifend felis, a sollicitudin neque suscipit vel.
        </p>
    </article>

    <article onmouseover="bg_Image(this)">
        <p>
            Vivamus egestas velit sed libero maximus, tempor dapibus lacus tempus. Proin tristique est eros, eget consectetur diam eleifend et.
            Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
        </p>
    </article>

    <article onmouseover="bg_Image(this)">
        <p>
            Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
            Donec faucibus metus et dolor sagittis accumsan. Morbi non dolor vestibulum, dictum risus nec, efficitur arcu.
        </p>
    </article>

    <article onmouseover="bg_Image(this)">
        <p>Aliquam suscipit urna nec faucibus euismod. Proin suscipit facilisis ullamcorper. In ultrices sodales massa, eu auctor eros interdum sed.</p>
    </article>

</section>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask] - and then edit your question, so that it contains an _actual question_ afterwards. Right now you have only given us your requirements, but you did not ask us anything specific. (And no, just “how do I do that” would not be considered specific either.)

Comment: I've changed the post, and specified my problems and questions (: thanks for letting me know that something lacked.

Comment: 1. is not actually about letter-spacing, but wants you to make `foo` into `f o o` instead.

Comment: If you have five columns right now, that would presumably be due to `style.width = "20%";` in combination with the floating. If you have to make that a different number of columns, this is the value you want to manipulate.

Comment: I know that, but the problem is more adding that style to all the articles, that seems to be my problem.

Comment: getElementsByTagName and a loop …